# Change starting point of stroke animation around a polygon?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have a hexagon shaped polygon with a stroke around it. I want to animate that stroke, which I've done, but I would love to have it start in a different place on the polygon.

This is the CSS that I have right now which works, I just want to change where the animation starts from.

```
.outline1 {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: #0d72b9;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}

g.icon .outline1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 808; 
    stroke-dashoffset:808; 
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; 
    fill:transparent;
 }

g.icon:hover .outline1{
    stroke-dashoffset:0; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is the svg

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 764.87 535.94">

    <g class="regional icon">
       <polygon class="cls-3 outline1" points="113.52 134.89 229.99 67.64 346.47 134.89 346.47 269.38 229.99 336.62 113.52 269.38 113.52 134.89"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```

The animation starts in the upper left corner but I'd like it to start in the bottom left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your start point.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/6j1ya433/1/) it's a right way to do it.

```css
.outline1 {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: #0d72b9;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}

g.icon .outline1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 808; 
    stroke-dashoffset:808; 
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; 
    fill:transparent;
 }

g.icon:hover .outline1{
    stroke-dashoffset:0; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 764.87 535.94">

    <g class="regional icon">
       <polygon class="cls-3 outline1" points="113.52 202.135 113.52 134.89 229.99 67.64 346.47 134.89 346.47 269.38 229.99 336.62 113.52 269.38"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it has to start from one of the points? I'd love for it to start in the middle of one of the segments of the stroke if that's possible. Sorry, I should have been more clear, didn't expect it would quite work the way you described.

Comment: @Dustin take a loop to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/6j1ya433/1), I also changed answer

Comment: Thanks. But how do you know what number to place in there and where to place it? I see you basically added a point, but did you do that with illustrator or a different way?

Comment: @Dustin basically, it's a simple math - I just added two numbers and then divided it to 2 (a+b/2). In `points` we have number values, `113.52 202.135 113.52 134.89 229.99 67.64 346.47 134.89 346.47 269.38 229.99 336.62 113.52 269.38`. Each point have two coordinates `x` and `y`. So, we have 6 point, and 14 values of coordinates on which our border is going throw. That's why we have two same `x` and `y` properties at start and end of our `points` value.

Answer (score 2):

The stroke starts where the path/polygon starts...change the start point.

```css
svg {
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.outline1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #0d72b9;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
g.icon .outline1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 808;
  stroke-dashoffset: 808;
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
  fill: pink;
}
g.icon:hover .outline1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 764.87 535.94">

  <g class="regional icon">
    <polygon class="cls-3 outline1" points=" 113.52 269.38 113.52 134.89 229.99 67.64 346.47 134.89 346.47 269.38 229.99 336.62 113.52 269.38 " />
  </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

For symmeterical shapes, it is much easier to add a CCS that directly rotate the shape.

```css
.outline1 {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: #0d72b9;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}

g.icon .outline1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 808; 
    stroke-dashoffset:808; 
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out; 
    fill:transparent;
 }

g.icon:hover .outline1{
    stroke-dashoffset:0; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
.outline1 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 764.87 535.94">
  
    <g class="regional icon">
       <polygon class="cls-3 outline1" points="113.52 134.89 229.99 67.64 346.47 134.89 346.47 269.38 229.99 336.62 113.52 269.38 113.52 134.89"/>
    </g>
  

</svg>
```